# Geocode table with addresses or lat/lon

Tags: geocoding

I am trying to set up a process to map locations to a street centerline by either an address or or by lat/lon (if no address exists).  Using ArcGIS Pro 3.0.x I have created a geocoder that only uses the Street Address Role to geocode locations - meaning all points geocode to a line.  All locations have a lat/lon even if no address exists.  When you geocode the table, you have the option to chose the different categories available based on how the geocoder was created.  I check the box for Coordinate System, but when I run my table through the geocoder, the locations without an address cannot be found.

Without creating an event layer, can a geocoder actually geocode Lat/Lon where no address exists?

[image: Geocoder Config]

[image: Results]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put the lat/lon or XY in the same field as the address.